# Конвертировать значение столбца в int

Tags: c#, devexpress

Пользовался Devexpress 11.1. Был определен метод ItemId

```
public int ItemId(DataRow row)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(row[ControllerList.IdNames[0]]);
}
```

Перешел на версию 17.2, пишет ошибку, что данный метод не найдет в gridcontroll.
Решил поискать в методах - ничего нет или я не заметил.

Пример использования:

```
ExperienceType ex = ExperienceType.Item(this.App, this.gridControl1.ItemId(this.gridView2.GetFocusedDataRow()));
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Это Вы метод из исходников `GridControl` скопировали? Еще, добавьте метку используемой GUI платформы (winforms/wpf/asp...)

Comment: Пробовали [`ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FocusedRowHandle.property), [`ColumnView.GetRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowHandle.method) для WinForms, либо [`DataViewBase.FocusedRowHandle`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataViewBase.FocusedRowHandle.property) для WPF?